# In a many to many relationship ensure that one entity is only tied to another entity

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

This is a bit of a convoluted question, but I can't quite get the logic right in my head.

I have three tables `TableA`, `TableB`, and `TableABBridge`. I need to retrieve all the values from `TableABBridge` in which records from `TableB` are only tied to a single record from `TableA`.

Essentially, I have a tool that allows users to edit a specific property on values in `TableA`. However, `TableB` also has this same property and it needs to be kept synchronized with the property from entities in `TableA`. So if I update the value in `TableA`, all of the values in `TableB` linked to the specific entity need to be updated, but ONLY if the entities in `TableB` are linked to ONLY ONE entity from `TableA`.

So for example

TableA

```
|   ID   |   Prop   |
|-------------------|
|       1|         1|
|       2|         3|
|       3|         3|
|-------------------|
```

TableB

```
|   ID   |   Prop   |
|-------------------|
|       1|         1|
|       2|         1|
|       3|         3|
|       4|         1|
|-------------------|
```

TableABBridge

```
|   AId   |   BId   |   
|-------------------|
|        1|        1|
|        1|        2|
|        1|        4|
|        2|        3|
|        3|        3|
|-------------------|
```

In the above example, I would be able to edit the property in `TableA` for `ID` 1 only as the values for `TableB` for `ID` 1, 2, and 4 are ONLY tied to `ID` 1 from `TableA`. However, I will not be able to edit the property for for `ID` 2 or 3 because they share a common entity from `TableB`.

So essentially, using Linq, I need to figure out how to get a list of `TableA` IDs that I am allowed to edit by querying `TableABBridge`.

The SQL to accomplish this is:

```
SELECT MAX(AId), BId 
FROM TableABBridge
GROUP BY BId
HAVING Count(AId) = 1
```

and the reverse (also needed)

```
SELECT a.Id
FROM    TableABBridge a
JOIN 
    (SELECT BId 
    FROM TableABBridge
    GROUP BY BId
    HAVING Count(AId) > 1) b ON b.BId = a.BId
```

Comment: The equivalent in Linq is a Join Statement.  See : https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/101-LINQ-Samples-3fb9811b

Comment: Are you using explicit or implicit "link" (bridge) table? Why don't you post the relevant part of your entity model.

Comment: There is actually an explicit link between all three entities. So values from `TableA` can traverse to `TableABBridge` and then to `TableB` and vice-versa.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A LINQ-ish way to do it is this:

```
var diffs = from b in context.Bs
            where b.ABs.Count() == 1
            let a = b.ABs.FistOrDefault().A
            where a.Prop != b.Prop
            select new { b, ValueA = a.Prop };

foreach(var diff in diffs)
{
    diff.b.Prop = diff.ValueA;
}
```

`context.Bs where b.ABs.Count() == 1` gives you all `Bs` having 1 junction record and hence one `A`. Then a structure is created in which the `B` and the value of A are stored side by side, so it's easy to do the update in a loop.

I said "LINQ-ish", because sometimes the natural way to express things in LINQ is different than what's more obvious in SQL (`b.ABs.Count()` vs. `GROUP BY`). It will generate a subquery for the counts, maybe making it less efficient than grouping. But it should also be kept in mind that LINQ `group by` isn't always translated into SQL `GROUP BY`.

Answer (score 0):

I believe one possible solution would be:

```
var bridges = context.TableABBridge.Select(n => new
{
    n.AId,
    n.BId
}).Distinct()
.GroupBy(n => n.BId, n => n.AId).Where(n => n.Count() > 1)
.Select(n=>n.Key);

var uneditable = context.TableABBridge.Where(n => bridges.Contains(n.BId)).Select(n => n.AId);

var editable = context.TableABBridge.Select(n => new
{
    n.AId,
    n.BId
}).Distinct()
.GroupBy(n => n.BId, n => n.AId).Where(n => n.Count() == 1)
.Select(n => n.FirstOrDefault().Value);
```